# Residualize an observation after fitting a model in group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to find the residual of observations after fitting a model per group. I would have thought the code looks something like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
   do(residual=resid(lm(y~x, data=.))) %>%
 ungroup()
```

but this collapses `df` and leaves no trace of the `x` variable. What I want is a data frame return that is something like

```
group |y| x| residual
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) dplyr** For purposes of example, this uses the `iris` data frame that comes with R.  I noticed that the code below chokes on the formula if we remove the double quotes but it works OK if the formula is passed as a character string as shown:

```
iris %>%
 group_by(Species) %>%
   do(mutate(., resid = resid(lm("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width", .)))) %>%
 ungroup()
```

**1a)** This variation also works even without a character string formula:

```
iris %>%
 group_by(Species) %>%
   do(cbind(., resid = resid(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .)))) %>%
 ungroup()
```

**1b)** and this variation also works:

```
iris %>%
 group_by(Species) %>%
   do(transform(., resid = resid(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .)))) %>%
 ungroup()
```

**2) Base R** We could also consider not using dplyr and just base R like this:

```
f <- function(ix) resid(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris, subset = ix))
transform(iris, resid = ave(seq_along(Species), Species, FUN = f))
```

**3) data.table**  If speed is of concern you might want to try data.table which is often the fastest approach and is also quite compact here:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(iris)
dt[, resid := resid(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .SD)), by = Species]
```

**3a)** Interestingly this variation of (1) works with data.table input and an actual formula (not character string).  Also, `do()` is not needed:

```
data.table(iris) %>%
 group_by(Species) %>%
   mutate(resid = resid(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, .))) %>%
 ungroup()
```

**Note:** I have added [dplyr issue 1648](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1648).

Comment: This works, thanks! But `cbind` seems like an expensive call to make. Is there a more efficient method, or is this what `mutate` et al are doing under the hood anyway?

Comment: added base and data.table solutions

Comment: added new (1).  Old (1) and (1a) are now (1a) and (1b).